# How to use Complex Constraint in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

This is what I want to implement

```
1. Customer can create a contact with name and phone number.
2. Customer can not create a contact with already existing phone number.
```

So I did like this…

```
schema "people" do
    field :name, :string
    field :phone_number, :string
    belongs_to :phonebook, Phonebook

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(%Person{} = person, attrs) do
    person
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :phone_number])
    |> validate_required([:name, :phone_number])
    |> unique_constraint(:phone_number])
  end
```

and in migration file

```
create unique_index(:people, [:phone_number)
```

But other customer can not create a contact with same number because other customer may has a same number.
So what is solution for this? I looked up Ecto document and found https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unique_constraint/3 1

Complex Constraints

is this correct solution?
I have tried this as documented, but it won’t work.

Comment: Is that code correct?  This `create unique_index(:people, [:phone_number)` doesn't look right to me.

Comment: oops There is a typo. it should be create unique_index(:people, [:phone_number])

Comment: You should edit your question then.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to have a `customer_id` field in the schema. Then apply the unique constraint to both the `phone_number` and `customer_id` field. In that case, the phone number will be scoped by the customer that added. When a customer creates a contact, set the contact's customer_id to the customer's id

In migration file

```
create table(:people) do
  ...
  add :customer_id, :integer
end

create unique_index(:people, [:phone_number, :customer_id], name: :people_phone_number_customer_id_index)
```

In model module

```
schema "people" do
field :name, :string
field :phone_number, :string
field :customer_id, :integer
belongs_to :phonebook, Phonebook

timestamps()
```

end

```
def changeset(%Person{} = person, attrs) do
person
|> cast(attrs, [:name, :phone_number, :customer_id])
|> validate_required([:name, :phone_number, :customer_id])
|> unique_constraint(:phone_number, name: :people_phone_number_customer_id_index)
end
```